# JavaFX VGrow TabPane on content change

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

In my JavaFX application, I have a `TabPane` in a `TitledPane`. Within the `TabPane` is a `VBox` which includes a button that increases the number of elements in that `VBox` (and as such, the height of the `VBox`).

However, I seem to be unable to get the `Tab`/`TabPane` to resize when the VBox grows. (Removing the `TabPane` and putting the `VBox` in the `TitledPane` directly leads to proper on-the-fly sizing.) However, changing the tab makes the `TabPane` realize that it is too small and resize.

Below is a small example FXML that can reproduce this. Click the button in the first tab any number of times then switch tabs. the `TabPane` will then resize to fit the new amount of content.

How can I make the `TabPane` resize on the button action?

---

fxml:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="FXMLController" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="700">
    <children>
        <TitledPane>
            <TabPane>
                <tabs>
                    <Tab>
                        <VBox fx:id="vBox">
                            <children>
                                <Button onAction="#addElement" />
                            </children>
                        </VBox>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab />
                </tabs>
            </TabPane>
        </TitledPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

controller:

```
@FXML VBox vBox;

@FXML void addElement() {
    vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Hello World"));
}
```

(of course with proper imports that I've left out for brevity's sake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the redraw to happen, you need to mark the `TabPane` as "dirty" -- that it requires recalculation of size in the UI.

This is done via calling the method `requestLayout()` on the `TabPane`.

See the docs for [`TabPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html#methods.inherited.from.class.javafx.scene.Parent) and its superclass [`Parent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#requestLayout--)

---

To make this example behave, add `fx:id="tabPane"` to the `<TabPane>` fxml node, then add the field `@FXML TabPane tabPane;` to the controller and the line `tabPane.requestLayout()` to `#addElement`.